# How to implement sine and cosine in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I want to implement this formula
[image]

I need a library to implement this. Thanks

Comment: Before being able to implement sine and cosine in Solidity, you first need a fixed-point math library. See [PRBMath](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math/tree/6d849c97831550e521a4bb363bb82eb78bb0415b/packages/prb-math).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The EVM is a quite limited, when possible it is better to do computations off-chain.

Comment: @Ismael yeap that makes more sense